# Preciso de um comando SQL para pegar todos os registros que são iguais em um campo e diferentes em outro

Tags: sql, mysqli

Pessoal tenho uma tabela que guarda dados do usuário como email/ip/cep/cidade/região, os registros são adicionados toda vez que o usuário faz login, então se o mesmo usuário fez login 2 vezes vai ser adicionado 2 registros, a ideia é verificar se o usuário está fazendo login do mesmo lugar comparando com os registros anteriores, então eu preciso de um comando SQL que me retorne todos os registros com e-mail igual mas com cep,cidade e ip diferentes.

Comment: tentou fazer a query? Se sim inclua na pergunta

Comment: tenho a logica na cabeça mas não sei como escrever a query, talvez algum comando que eu desconheça.

Comment: Pesquise por "group by" e "having" , "subselects" , veja também "primary key" "unique key".

Comment: Verifique se atende: `SELECT * FROM sua_tabela a INNER JOIN sua_tabela b ON (a.email = b.email AND (a.cep <> b.cep OR a.cidade <> b.cidade OR a.ip <> b.ip));`.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente muito obg!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem dois jeitos de resolver essa sua situação:

1. Caso precise que todos os atributos (cep,cidade e ip) sejam diferentes:

`SELECT * FROM tabela_login tab1 INNER JOIN tabela_login tab2 on (tab1.email = tab2.email) AND (tab1.cep <> tab2.cep AND tab1.cidade <> tab2.cidade AND tab1.ip <> tab2.ip)`

2. Caso precise que pelo menos um dos atributos (cep,cidade e ip) sejam diferentes:

`SELECT * FROM tabela_login tab1 INNER JOIN tabela_login tab2 on (tab1.email = tab2.email) AND (tab1.cep <> tab2.cep OR tab1.cidade <> tab2.cidade OR tab1.ip <> tab2.ip)`

Por questão de performance na query eu aconselharia a retirar o atributo cidade das condições, uma vez que o CEP já aponta para uma determinada cidade também, então está comparando informações as quais uma está contida na outra (cidade em CEP).